# Client-side search doesn't strip formatting in Bootstrap-table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

I am using **Bootstrap-table's** client-side search functionality. In general, it works very well; my only problem is that it does not strip formatting...

E.g., if I have a **User name** column and I put there a value like this:

```
<td><strong>Smith</strong> John</td>
```

Then **Search** will find strings "Smith" or "John", but searching for "Smith John" will match zero rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using [Custom Search](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/custom-search.html).

First, add `data-custom-search="customSearchMethod"` to `<table>`, then implement it like e.g.:

```
function customSearchMethod(data, text) {
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    return data.filter(function(row) {
        let cellText = Object.values(row).join().toLowerCase().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
        return cellText.indexOf(text) > -1;
    });
}
```